# How to access Google drive image in canvas

Tags: canvas, google-drive-api, cross-domain, google-picker

I want to export google drive image using DataUrl() from canvas. To make CORS-enabled images with canvas, i was added cross="anonymous" attribute in img tag.

```
<img crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0By1uZFYMEbpuSFlFa1h5Y2o0a1k&export=download" id="media_img" />
```

But it showing error

> Redirect from 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0By1uZFYMEbpuSFlFa1h5Y2o0a1k&export=download' to 'https://doc-0g-ac-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/rn783m94dmuq387i8t74c2cse5pfvoti/1526457600000/05627031542031468169/*/0By1uZFYMEbpuSFlFa1h5Y2o0a1k?e=download' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8002' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You can try the HTTP request specified [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export#request). `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/export`

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes you can use this cors-proxy https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com

But it is slow and unsteady - so for production code you should setup simple file serwer with allow CORS or setup you own proxy serwer which allow CORS. (below snippet is slow, you need to wait some time before img appear)

```html
<img crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0By1uZFYMEbpuSFlFa1h5Y2o0a1k&export=download" id="media_img" width=250 />
```